# PIL.Image.fromarray produces distorted image after np.reshape

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an array (numpy) of shape (10000,1296) that I want to save as 10,000 images of 36x36 size. All values in the array are in the range `(0,255)`. So I have used this code to do that (which worked well):

```
for i, line in enumerate(myarray):
    img = Image.new('L',(36,36))
    img.putdata(line)
    img.save(str(i)+'.png')
```

I wanted to replace this code using the `Image.fromarray` method, but the resulting pictures are distorted beyond recognition compared to the original method. First I tried this:

```
myarray = myarray.reshape(10000,36,36)
for i, line in enumerate(myarray):
    img = Image.fromarray(line, 'L')
    img.save(str(i)+'.png')
```

Which didn't work. So to debug I thought I would try just one item and did this:

```
Image.fromarray(myarray[0].reshape(36,36), 'L').save('test.png')
```

And again - garbled distorted image.

So I figured either `fromarray` isn't working like I thought it should, or my `reshape` is too naive and messes up the data, but I am not able to fix this. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What is `myarray.dtype`?

Comment: `dtype=float32`

Comment: `L` mode is for data that represents luminance. The data should be of dtype `uint8`. Luminance values should be ints ranging from 0 to 255. So try `myarray = myarray.astype('uint8')` before the loop.

Comment: well that worked so thank you but I don't really understand why since the values were whole numbers even before the conversion and I would think that `fromarray` would be able to handle it the same way that `putdata` obviously handles it... If you could post your comment as an answer with some minimal explanation I would accept it

Comment: Also, is there any other mode besides `L` I should have used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PIL's `L` mode is a grayscale mode for data that represents luminance
(brightness).  The data is expected to be ints from 0 to 255. If you create a PIL Image by passing a NumPy array to `Image.fromarray` with `mode='L'`, the dtype of the array should be `uint8`. Therefore use

```
myarray = myarray.astype('uint8')
```

to ensure that the arrays passed to `Image.fromarray` have dtype `uint8`.

---

`uint8`s are unsigned 8-bit ints. `float32`s are 32-bit floats. They are 4 times as wide as a `uint8`. `Image.fromarray` views the underlying data in the NumPy array as `uint8`s, reads enough bytes to fill the image, and ignores the rest. So each 32-bit float becomes four 8-bit ints and each of those 8-bit ints colors a different pixel.

In other words, the following `assert` passes:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

line = np.arange(256).reshape(16, 16).astype('float32')
img = Image.fromarray(line, 'L')
line2 = np.asarray(img)
assert (line.view('uint8').ravel()[:256].reshape(16, 16) == line2).all()
```

This is why using `myarray` without converting to `uint8`s creates a garbled image.

---

Alternatively, instead of converting `myarray` to `uint8`s you could
read the data in `mode='F'` (float mode):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

line = np.arange(256).reshape(16, 16).astype('float32')
img = Image.fromarray(line, 'F').convert('L')
img.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

which yields

[image]

See [this page](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode) for a list of all the possible PIL modes.

Comment: Amazing detailed answer, and of course fixed my problem, thank you